# The constructor JSONObject(String) is undefined error - not able to resolve

Tags: java, json, servlets

I am trying to get some variables in servlet which are all passed through ajax call. But i am getting constructor JSONobject(string) is undefined error. I have imported required lib also. Please help

```js
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.JsonArray;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;

import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;
import org.json.*;


public class insertserv extends HttpServlet {
 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
 
 
 protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
 {    
  
  System.out.println("I am inside insert");
     String json = "";
  
  
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(request.getInputStream()));
    

             if (br != null) {
                 json = br.readLine();
             }
  
    System.out.println(json);
    
    JSONObject wholedata= new JSONObject(json);
  
    
    response.setContentType("application/json"); 
  PrintWriter out= response.getWriter();
  
 }
}
```

Comment: What do you see when you print the json?

Comment: i am getting the data , what i passed from ajax call "data: JSON.stringify({"test" :masterdata})," i am getting required data. but at next line i am getting constructor error

Comment: This looks like Java, so I've added such tag. If I'm wrong please correct it.

Answer (score 5):

removed org.json.simple.JSONObject; and updated with org.json.JSONObject; its solved my issue

Comment: As I edited like you stated above, I am getting **The import org.json.JSONObject cannot be resolved error**. I have maven dependency json-simple version 1.1.1 added to my pom.xml.  How does your dependency looks like ? @Jsel